# Failed to start Flutter renderer: No GL implementation is available

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, fedora

i create a simple "Hello Word" in flutter and enable web and linux platform to test is both,in chrome everything was ok and i see my first web app in flutter "Hello word",but in my desktop apps on Linux starting but not displaying anything and give me this message in terminal

```
libEGL warning: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1) (search paths /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri, suffix _dri)


** (app:22248): WARNING **: 05:45:50.289: Failed to start Flutter renderer: No GL implementation is available
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly.
Error launching application on Linux.
```

and this is my hello word apps

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i use fedora 35 beta
i hope u can help me guys and thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error message, it seems like it is an error with `glibc` or `glibc-devel` not being installed. I am running Fedora 34, so I can't search F35's repos but if you run `dnf repoquery --whatprovides 'libpthread.so*'` it should give you the name of the packages required for it to run.

If the packages are already installed, please let me know and I will see if I can help you out by editing this answer.

**EDIT:** I don't have any experience with Snap but, after some digging, it looks like you can't expose certain folders in Snap, so a quick (albeit dirty) fix is to add the file `flutter` cannot find to the folder containing the Snap package.

You could also try this:

```sh
$ snap run --shell <snap>.<command>
$ env
XDG_VTNR=1
SSH_AGENT_PID=5543
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
SNAP_USER_COMMON=/home/<user>/snap/<snap>/common
SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:
SNAP_COMMON=/var/snap/<snap>/common
[...]
```

Edit the line from `SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:` to `SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/path/to/folder/containing/libpthread`, save the edits and try to launch the app again.

You can find where `libpthread` is located by opening your file manager, browse to `/` (in GNOME this is under 'Other locations' > 'Computer' in the left-hand navigation pane), unhide hidden folders (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) and use the search function. This should show where the file is located (on my machine it's under `/usr/lib64`) and you add the folder to the `SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: i install all the packages but its still the same problem

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like you are using it through Snap - is this correct?

Comment: same problem here, flutter installed through git on an AARCH64 (JingOS) sys

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the snap install, what worked for me is replacing the snap version with the [manual install](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually) from github. You can also use the tarball.

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

now to add flutter to path:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Assuming ur flutter install was at /home/user/ add this at the end of the file:

`export PATH="$PATH:/flutter/bin"`

If ur flutter install is somewhere else then change the directory accordingly

After saving and exiting, refresh ur .bashrc file with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now check if its added to path with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you see a /flutter/bin then ur doing fine. To check if flutter's installed:

```
flutter  --version
```

To add any missing dependencies (if ur on **Fedora**) use:

```
sudo dnf install bash curl file git unzip which xz zip mesa-libGLU clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config gtk3-devel
```

On **Ubuntu** based distros it is

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev
```